# How to combine two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
const participants = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Tom', gender: 'm'}
    ,{id: 2, name: 'Paul', gender: 'm'}
    ,{id: 3, name: 'Igor', gender: 'm'}
    ,{id: 4, name: 'Anna', gender: 'f'}
    ,{id: 5, name: 'Mary', gender: 'f'}
    ,{id: 6, name: 'Alice', gender: 'f'}
];
```

Now, for each "round" I want to let each man be paired with a girl.
Something like:

```
First round:
Tom and Anna
Paul and Mary
Igor and Alice

Second round:
Tom and Mary
Paul and Alice
Igor and Anna

Thirth round:
Tom and Alice
Paul and Anna
Igor and Mary
```

However, it could happen that there are only 2 girls (Anna and Mary). In that case, for each round, one of the guy should be "alone".

What is the best way to create an algorithm for that? I have created an algorithm that does not really do the job the right way, as the result is not following the scenario described above.

```js
const participants = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Tom', gender: 'm' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Paul', gender: 'm' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Igor', gender: 'm' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Anna', gender: 'f' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Mary', gender: 'f' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Alice', gender: 'f' }
];
const men = participants.filter(el => el.gender === 'm');
const women = participants.filter(el => el.gender === 'f');

let currentIndex = 0;
let pairs = [];


men.forEach((el, index) => {
    const tmpPair = [];
    men.forEach((el2, index2) => {
        let woman = null;
        if ((index2 + currentIndex) >= women.length) {
            woman = women[0];
        } else {
            woman = women[index2 + currentIndex];
        }
        tmpPair.push({ man: men[index2], woman: woman });
    });
    currentIndex++;

    pairs.push(tmpPair);
});
console.log(pairs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works for you?

```js
const participants = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tom',
    gender: 'm'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Paul',
    gender: 'm'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Igor',
    gender: 'm'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Anna',
    gender: 'f'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Mary',
    gender: 'f'
  }
];

const men = participants.filter(p => p.gender === 'm');
const women = participants.filter(p => p.gender == 'f');

const round = men.length;

for (i = 0; i < round; i += 1) {
  console.log(`Round ${i + 1}`);
  men.forEach((m, index) => {
    const wIndex = (index + i) % round;
    const woman = women[wIndex] ? ` and ${women[wIndex].name}` : '';
    console.log(`${m.name}${woman}`);
  })
  console.log(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
const men = participants.filter(el => el.gender === 'm');
const women = participants.filter(el => el.gender === 'f');

var maxlen = Math.max(men.length, women.length)
let pairs = [], pair;

for (var i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
    pair={};
     if (men[i] && men[i] != '') pair.man = men[i].name;
     if (women[i] && women[i] != '') pair.woman = women[i].name;
     pairs.push(pair)
}
// pairs is an array like [{"man":"Tom", "woman":"Mary"}, ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed your sample to get rid of one of the females.

Notice in particular the use of `Math.random` in the array sorting function.  This is assuming your need isn't for 3 rounds in particular, but to create a round on-the-fly.

Secondarily, notice the need to get both the higher of the length of males and females before you iterate.  It's tempting to take advantage of the often overlooked index parameter in `Array.map` to write this out in fully fluent syntax.  But I thought it best to loop the old-fashioned way so that you also cover the need of too few men.

```js
const participants = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Tom', gender: 'm'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Paul', gender: 'm'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Igor', gender: 'm'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Anna', gender: 'f'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Mary', gender: 'f'}
];

let getGender = (gender) => 
    participants
        .filter(p => p.gender == gender)
        .sort((a,b) => Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

let males = getGender('m');
let females = getGender('f');
let pairs = [];

let n = Math.max(males.length, females.length);

for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    pairs.push({ man: males[i], woman: females[i] });

for(let pair of pairs)
    console.log(
        pairs.man && pairs.woman 
        ? `${pair.man.name} and ${pair.woman.name}`
        : `${pair.man.name || pair.woman.name} is alone`
    );
```